# WebGL Read pixels from floating point render target

Tags: webgl

There is some confusion [e.g.](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/archives/1210/msg00090.html) in terms of support levels for *rendering* to floating point textures in WebGL. The OES_texture_float extension does not seem to mandate it per se, as per [Optional support for FLOAT textures as FBO attachments (deprecated)](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/), but it looks like some vendors went ahead and implement it. Therefore my basic understanding is that rendering to floating point textures actually works in non-ES desktop environments. I have not been able to *read* from the floating point render target directly though.

My question is whether there is a way to read from a floating point texture using a WebGLContext::readPixels() call and a Float32Array destination? Thanks in advance.

Attached is a script that succeeds reading from a byte texture, but fails for a float texture:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function run_test(use_float) {
    // Create canvas and context
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");

    // Decide on types to user for texture
    var texType, bufferFmt;
    if (use_float) {
        texType = gl.FLOAT;
        bufferFmt = Float32Array;
    } else {
        texType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
        bufferFmt = Uint8Array;
    }

    // Query extension
    var OES_texture_float = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
    if (!OES_texture_float) {
        throw new Error("No support for OES_texture_float");
    }

    // Clear
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Create texture
    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 512, 512, 0, gl.RGBA, texType, null);

    // Create and attach frame buffer
    var fbo = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        throw new Error("gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE");
    }

    // Clear
    gl.viewport(0, 0, 512, 512);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    var pixels = new bufferFmt(4 * 512 * 512);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 512, 512, gl.RGBA, texType, pixels);

    if (pixels[0] !== (use_float ? 1.0 : 255)) {
        throw new Error("pixels[0] === " + pixels[0].toString());
    }
}

function main() {
    run_test(false);
    console.log('Test passed using GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE');
    run_test(true);
    console.log('Test passed using GL_FLOAT');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='main()'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The readPixels is limited to the RGBA format and the UNSIGNED_BYTE type ([WebGL specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/#5.14.12)). However there are some methods for "packing" floats into RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE described here:

http://concord-consortium.github.io/lab/experiments/webgl-gpgpu/webgl.html

Comment: This is no longer correct. See @nraynaud's answer, and David Gilbertson's comment below it. :-)

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately it still seems that reading out RGBA components as bytes is the only way for WebGL. If you need to encode a float into a pixel value you can use the following:

In your fractal shader (GLSL/HLSL):

```
float shift_right (float v, float amt) { 
    v = floor(v) + 0.5; 
    return floor(v / exp2(amt)); 
}
float shift_left (float v, float amt) { 
    return floor(v * exp2(amt) + 0.5); 
}
float mask_last (float v, float bits) { 
    return mod(v, shift_left(1.0, bits)); 
}
float extract_bits (float num, float from, float to) { 
    from = floor(from + 0.5); to = floor(to + 0.5); 
    return mask_last(shift_right(num, from), to - from); 
}
vec4 encode_float (float val) { 
    if (val == 0.0) return vec4(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    float sign = val > 0.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0; 
    val = abs(val); 
    float exponent = floor(log2(val)); 
    float biased_exponent = exponent + 127.0; 
    float fraction = ((val / exp2(exponent)) - 1.0) * 8388608.0; 
    float t = biased_exponent / 2.0; 
    float last_bit_of_biased_exponent = fract(t) * 2.0; 
    float remaining_bits_of_biased_exponent = floor(t); 
    float byte4 = extract_bits(fraction, 0.0, 8.0) / 255.0; 
    float byte3 = extract_bits(fraction, 8.0, 16.0) / 255.0; 
    float byte2 = (last_bit_of_biased_exponent * 128.0 + extract_bits(fraction, 16.0, 23.0)) / 255.0; 
    float byte1 = (sign * 128.0 + remaining_bits_of_biased_exponent) / 255.0; 
    return vec4(byte4, byte3, byte2, byte1); 
}

 // (the following inside main(){}) return your float as the fragment color
 float myFloat = 420.420;
 gl_FragColor = encode_float(myFloat);
```

Then back on the JavaScript side, after your draw call has been made you can extract the encoded float value of each pixel with the following:

```
var pixels = new Uint8Array(CANVAS.width * CANVAS.height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
pixels = new Float32Array(pixels.buffer);

// pixels now contains an array of floats, 1 float for each pixel
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I can verify that this works well. I used your solution in this work: https://github.com/stharding/function-plotter

Comment: No problem Stephen, great work by the way; feel free to reach out directly if you have any more questions: adrian [at] gatosomina [dot] com

Comment: thanks a lot for this, it worked like a charm and gave me the precision I needed for a simulation + I didn't know that Float32Array( ArrayBuffer ) would convert Ints to floats, that's very handy :) thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I'm adding my recent discoveries: Chrome will let you read floats, as part of the implementation defined format ([search for "readPixels" in the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#5.4)), Firefox implements the [WEBGL_color_buffer_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_color_buffer_float/) extension, so you can just load the extension and read your floats, I have not been able to read floats with Safari.

Comment: Do you know if this means that this functionality is expected in webgl 2?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#readpixels yes, I think so.

Comment: Thanks very much for this comment. I see in chrome I can call `gl.getContext("experimental-webgl")` and then call `gl.readPixels(0,0,width,height,gl.RGB,gl.FLOAT,buf)` while I have a floating point FBO bound, where `buf` is a `Float32Array`. But how do I use the extension in firefox? I can call `gl.getExtension("WEBGL_color_buffer_float")`, and it returns a `WEBGL_color_buffer_float {  }` but what do I do with it?

Comment: Answering my own question -- it seems in firefox only `gl.RGBA` is supported with `gl.FLOAT`, but once you call `gl.getExtension("WEBGL_color_buffer_float")` this does seem to work.

Comment: FWIW, the 1.0.3 version of the spec [linked above](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0.3/#5.14.12) doesn't mention `FLOAT`, but the [latest version (of WebGL1) does](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.12).

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed since WebGL shipped. Basically WebGL requires that you can call readPixels with format = RGBA and type = UNSIGNED_BYTE. Otherwise, the implementation is allowed one other implementation defined format/type combo per framebuffer attachment type.

You can query what that format/type combo is like this

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, someFramebuffer);
const format = gl.getParameter(gl.IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT);
const type = gl.getParameter(gl.IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE);
```

Unfortunately, it's implementation defined. So for example, checking my personal devices at least one of them, my Nvidia Macbook Pro, reports RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE, in Chrome. The other browsers/devices report RGBA/FLOAT

WebGL2 requires being able to read as RGBA/FLOAT for floating point texture, if `EXT_color_buffer_float` extension is enabled.

A workaround in WebGL1 could include writing to RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE as FLOAT. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63827836/is-it-possible-to-do-a-rgba-to-float-and-back-round-trip-and-read-the-pixels-in/63830492#63830492). You could either change your shader. Or you could add another pass that reads your floating point result texture and writes to a RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture, maybe 4x as large to get all RGBA values.