# How to read back RGBA floats from a texture

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl

I have a 512x512 texture I stored in WebGL as

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 512, 512, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)
```

I wrote to this texture afterwards. Now I'd like to get the RGBA floats back.

It is my understanding that this texture uses 4 channels (RGBA) to store the floats, and those floats are normalized [0;1].

I'm doing the following to read it back:

```
  var framebuffer;
  framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
var mydata= new Uint8Array(512 * 512 * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 512, 512, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, mydata);
```

but I'm reading garbage values.

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: First do a `gl.checkFramebufferStatus() == gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` before `readPixels` to see if your frameBuffer is working as intended, then check if the data you written to the texture is correct. Maybe draw them on the screen and use the colors to reason about the correctness of the data? Also keep in mind the Uint8Array doesnt store "floats" between 0 to 1 but rather ints from 0 to 255.

Comment: but they do represent floats, right?

Comment: Floats have very specific meaning in cs so in that sense they are not floats. If you mean can they represent values between 0 to 1, then they can be. Just divide by 255. There is https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_color_buffer_float/ for working with real floating point textures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebGL Read pixels from floating point render target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981163/webgl-read-pixels-from-floating-point-render-target)