# aframe:How to get pixels from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, aframe

I want to read and process the pixel data rendered in a-frame.
I tried the code below

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
params = {
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
},
gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl', params);
var pixels = new Uint8Array(canvas.width * canvas.height * 4);
gl.readPixels(
    0,
    0,
    canvas.width,
    canvas.height,
    WebGLRenderingContext.RGBA,
    WebGLRenderingContext.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    pixels
    );
```

But the pixels array was left of 0, 0, 0, 0
How can I read the pixel data on the canvas?
I'd appreciate it if you could answer this problem

Comment: `left of 0, 0, 0, 0` what do you mean? why are you dealing with four dimensional space?

Comment: maybe this can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981163/webgl-read-pixels-from-floating-point-render-target

Comment: Of course it's `0,0,0,0`. You created a new canvas and rendered nothing to it. It starts out and `0,0,0,0`. What's the question?

Comment: The pixels array is one dimensional.

And I also referred to the link presented by Mr. Dex, but since I could not solve it, I made a new question here.

I am using a tag-based VR creation framework "A-FRAME"
Reference link[link](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/hello-world/)

I want to read the pixel data of the screen created by this framework.

Answer (score 1):

In [the demo you posted](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/hello-world/), find and put a breakpoint on the line that says:

```
    _gl = _context || _canvas.getContext( 'webgl', attributes )
```

Take a look at `attributes`, it's an options object, and among other settings it contains this option:

```
    preserveDrawingBuffer: false
```

Although your original post shows you manually setting this option to `true`, your option has not carried through into the demo you posted.  If you can make this option take effect, you should be able to read the pixels back.