# Download framebuffer as HDR

Tags: javascript, webgl, hdr

In an HTML5 canvas 2d context the method `toDataURL` lets one download the canvas'content as an image, with color values from 0 to 255.

To do the same from a webgl context, I guess a simple way is to use `readPixels` and copy the resulting buffer values in a 2d canvas, then use the previous method to download the result, with color values still from 0 to 255. That means, values with greater range will be clamped.

So what if we want the image to be an HDR, in a float format ?

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981163/webgl-read-pixels-from-floating-point-render-target) details how to read float values from a render target, but what can we do with the resulting `Float32Array` to convert it to an HDR and download it ?

Comment: what's the desired download image format?

Comment: well .hdr could be neat :)

Comment: You'll have to encode the file yourself according to the [file format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/pic/).

Comment: Yep saw that, seems like it is the only way, thx.

Comment: This may help. http://www.xinapse.com/Manual/raw_converter.html You can save the pixel data as a raw binary dump and then use software such as this to convert. From memory Photoshop could load raw pixel dumps but its been so long since I have used PS I can not remember if it supported floats or even if current version still have that import option. Or https://github.com/imbcmdth/logluv-encoding can help you convert to a pixel format more commonly used in HDR encodings reducing the work needed to write a custom encoder