# GLSL Texture Precision

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I am trying to make a fluid simulation using textures and webgl/three.js. I have most of the concepts implemented and they work okay, I ran into a few problems along the way. I For example I tried using  Gauss-Seidel relaxation as suggested by Jos Stam (http://www.intpowertechcorp.com/GDC03.pdf). I implemented it using render targets.  The problem I have was that the output of textures by default is unsignedbye. I wasn't able to get a very good diffusion working because of this. I tried using half floats and floats, but the problem is they take way too long. I worry I wont be able to get the fluid simulation working as I want due to this constraint. Is there an alternative or way to approach this that I am unaware of? I tried using shorts but it says they aren't compatible with the mode I am using (RGBA).

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981163/webgl-read-pixels-from-floating-point-render-target) will help you

Comment: Thanks for the response. it wasn't exactly related to what I was looking for.